# I'm building an app with Node, Express, and MongoDB. Is AngularJS necessary?

Tags: architecture, javascript, web-development, node.js, angularjs

Node, Express, and MongoDB are really connected so I can understand why they are frequently used together. For a web app of medium complexity, can I get away with only using HTML/CSS and EJS for the front end? I don't really understand how AngularJS fits into the MEAN stack. Can someone elaborate?

Comment: AngularJS is not necessary.  There are lots of choices for a front-end framework.  You can choose anything you want from plain HTML to an encompassing framework.  As with all tools like this, it depends entirely upon your needs and it would not be a short conversation to fully understand your needs and match it to an appropriate framework.

Comment: You do not need any of these components at all. It is a matter of personal (dis)taste, what you throw together. I would say, that you have to look at the point in time, when this combo was hyped. Then Angular was the hyped frontendtool. Hyped means here: it was present on fora and talks. This says nothing about its qualities in any sense. I am voting for »close« because it causes too opinionated and too broad answers.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing from the MEAN stack that cannot be used without each other is Express that cannot be used without Node (but you can use Node without Express).

So of course you can use anything else for the frontend - React, Ember, vanilla JS, anything.

Also Mongo is in no way coupled with Node or Express. You can use any database with Node and Express, and you can use any runtime and framework with Mongo.

For other Node frameworks see:

- http://nodeframework.com/

For other "stacks" based on Node see:

- [MERN stack](http://mern.io/)
- [SANE stack](http://sanestack.com/)

Comment: You could improve your answer, when explaining the reasons why or why Angular is or isn't necessary. So far you talked about which components you could use separately.